# python display a character at a time

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm recreating a part of pokemon yellow (trying to make it as close to the original as possible) And for 2 days now I'm searching a smart and efficient way to render and display a string one character at a time in the textbox, just like the pokemon games!(By the way I'm using pygame and python). Does anyone know any way of achieving this? I've tried many things but when rendering one character at a time, there is always inadequate space between them.
Sorry for the long question!
Cheers,
Alex

(edit) Thanks for your interest guys!!!
I'm not sure if I know the correct way to display my code here, If I should just
copy paste it in here or upload in dropbox or somewhere else..

(edit2) Just to clarify, i use the font at size 28, so the way I'm trying to render the characters right now, is to make a list where every element has the format (character_to_render,x_pos_to_render,y_pos_to_render). The next character would be (character2_to_render,**x_pos_to_render + 28**,y_pos_to_render). But approaching the problem this way, leaves inadequate space between some characters and some others are just fine.

(Edit 3) : Thanks for all your answers guys ! After closely observing the emulator, I noticed that the inadequate spacing between rendered characters is apparent there as well! So I'll just ignore this issue Andover on with my project !! Cheers and have a nice day!

Comment: Can you show us the things you've tried? Maybe the solution is just a simple modification of one of those things.

Comment: Right! give me a couple of minutes to make the code look a bit clearer

Comment: I'd probably use a generator and embed sleep into it so that a simple iteration would yield what I want, including the time breaks...

But I'm not familiar with pygame

Comment: Reut thanks for your answer! Basically I'm doing something similar to your answer. I append every character after a short period of time to a list called to_render where everly element in this list is in the format (surface_to_render,x,y) and I blit it to the screen.The problem is that some characters have inadequate spaces between them and some others don't!

Comment: Try monospaced font..

Comment: Thanks for your intesrest Sayakiss! I didn't really know what monospaced fonts were, but I'll do some research.

Comment: @user3387584 the font with fixed-width and leaves equal space between every charecter.

Comment: @Sayakiss Right I'll see if I can find anything helpful! Cheers :)

Comment: Add one character at a time to a string and render the whole string. If you clean the background in every cycle you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the best solution that I have come up with so far.

You want to be able to display a string, but you only want to do it one character at a time. With strings you can do something like `string[0:len(string)]` which will return the whole string. So what I am thinking and please correct me if I'm wrong, but say you lower the FPS for a couple seconds, or If you do not want to do this because you still want to accept user input to skip the text.

So you have your while loop, and you check for if text is being displayed. If it is, you want to add a new letter to the string that you are displaying to the screen. I would recommend using a class for the text displayed on the screen.

```
surf = pygame.Surface(80, 80)
Text = TextBoxString("Hello World")
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 18)
while true:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            Text.showAll()
    surf.fill((0,0,0))
    text = font.render(Text.currentString, (0,0,0))
    surf.blit(text, (0,0))
    Text.addOn()


class TextBoxString:
    def __init__(self, string):
        #string that you will be dealing with
        self.totalString = string
        self.currentString = string[0]
        #how many characters you want shown to the screen
        self.length = 0
        #this means that every four times through your 
        #while loop a new char is displayed
        self.speed = 4
    def addOn(self) #adds one to the loop num and then checks if the loop num equals the speed
        self.loopNum += 1
        if self.loopNum == self.speed:
            self.length += 1
            self.loopNum=0
        self.currentString = totalString[0: self.length]
    def showAll(self):
        self.length = len(self.totalString)
        self.currentString = [0: self.length]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you put on this man :) I worked on my approach as well and It's working better! Cheers